# Float to Scientific notation

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, scipy, floating-point-precision

I have x = 364567.254831

I have tried like this but it doesn't work

```
x=364567.254831
print '%0.14E'%x
```

output is

```
3.64567254831000E+05
```

I want like this

```
 0.36364567254831000E+06
```

Comment: Normal scientific notation is `3.64e+05` and not `0.364e+06`.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Are you sure you want to use a non-standard format?

Comment: I have some Fortran code written to read the data in the format which I have mentioned. So I want to convert my data in that format. And I have noticed that using ArcGIS workstation using UNGENERATE command, the output is in the similar format

Comment: Your Fortran code refuses normal scientific notation?  Can you fix it?

Comment: Is it possible to fix it here in python ?